# Vim's E49: Invalid scroll size

Tags: vim

I am trying to set the scroll distance to 3 in Vim. This is what I have tried in my
`.vimrc` file.

```
setlocal scroll=3
autocmd VimEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWritePre,BufWritePost * setlocal scroll=3
```

None of this works, or it only works for some time and then it stops working when I 
change the tab or I make other actions. The error seems to happen randomly or at least I
haven't been able to find any pattern.

Apparently, [I am not the only one](https://github.com/alxndr/dotfiles/blob/6615a14ff69b5ffaf69d4a06854ee7adc0d20aad/.vimrc#L38) having this problem.

Comment: `scroll` is used only by the CTRL-U and CTRL-D, both of these moves the cursor unlike CTRL-E. See `:h scrolling` for more information.

Comment: Oh, I know. I should have been more explicit in my question. C-u is not working as expected. That's why I choose to use c-e instead.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution is to use `<C-e>` and  `<C-y>` instead with these mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-e> 3<C-e> 
nnoremap <C-y> 3<C-y>
```

I'm sure someone has a good explanation of why this is happening, though.

Comment: Same exact problem.
I guess it's coming from a plugin but since I installed 2000 of those, not sure where it's coming from.